# Directory diff in bash script

Tags: bash, diff

I have a bash script that expands two archives (jar files) into two directories and then does a diff of the two folders. I want the diff to be piped into a file so I do this in the bash file.

```
diff -r $originalJarExtracted $assembledJarExtracted >target/$diffList
```

While this works it also stops the script and anything afterwards is not executed. How can I get diff to pipe its output into the file and for the script to keep going. I looked at the info and man pages for diff but could not get this to work. I am running the script on the mac btw.

Just for reference the scripts are [on github](https://github.com/mosabua/android4maven-lint)

Comment: The script will keep executing. Post the whole script (or a reduced script that exhibits the problem, if the whole script is very long).

Comment: Have you tried putting it in background `&`? A nice trick when debugging your scripts is to execute it like `bash -x yourscript` It will output the execution trace with the contents of variables to standard output/error.

Answer (score 6):

Wild guess: your script is operating under `set -e` (synonym: `set -o errexit`), which causes the shell to exit if any commands returns a nonzero status (conventionally indicating failure). If so, it will exit if `diff` finds any difference, because `diff` returns the status 1 if it finds differences. If this is the problem, then change that line to

```
diff -r "$originalJarExtracted" "$assembledJarExtracted" >"target/$diffList" ||
[ $? -eq 1 ]
```

Then the script will only exit if `diff` returns a status other than 0 (no difference) or 1 (differences), i.e. only if there was an error such as a missing file.

Comment: Your wild guess was correct. If I take set -e out the script works. Adding your suggested changes however does not fix it, but at least I can run the scripts all in one now..